# Does potential difference only indicate how much energy each coulomb have ,

Tags: electricity

Does potential difference only indicate how much energy each coulomb have,  or make current flow, or do both?

Answer (score 0):

Both.

In an electric field such as that arising from charges on the terminals of a battery, the pd, $\Delta V$, between two points, A and B,  is indeed defined as the change in electrical potential energy per unit charge going from A to B.

But if there is a conductor between A and B, the greater the value of $\Delta V$, the more the current through the conductor. The reason for this is that a greater $\Delta V$ corresponds to a greater magnitude, $E$, of electric field strength (force per unit charge). The relationship is $$E=-\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta s}$$in which $\Delta s$ is an increment of distance in the direction of steepest fall, $\Delta V$, in potential. [This is a direct consequence of $Work=\mathbf{F.\Delta s}$.] A greater electric field strength exerts a greater force on the charge carriers in the conductor, leading to a greater drift velocity – and a greater current!